# Adding a JScrollPane to JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing, mousewheel, jpopupmenu

I'm trying to add a `JScrollPane` with a custom component in it to a `JPopupMenu`. It works perfectly, it also shows the vertical scroll bar when needed. But when I try to scroll using the mouse wheel, the popup menu disappears.

Anybody got an idea?

(If it's possible I want to use a `JPopupmenu`, because it is well integrated into the different OS. I know I can build a Window on my own which looks like a popup menu, but it is too much workaround..)

Comment: Could you please give us some of the code you used that reproduces the issue you're having? It would greatly help us helping you :) Maybe you could post some [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

With `MouseWheelEvent e`, you should add the following:

```
e.consume();
```

to "consume this event so that it will not be processed in the default manner by the source which originated it."

It worked for me.